# pandas groupby converts dtype of grouped columns from string to object

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, dtype

I am facing an issue with the fact that pandas groupby is coercing a string column into an object column for no good reason.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"x":["a", "b"], "y":[1, 2]})
>>> df = df.astype({"x":"string", "y":"Int64"})
>>> df.dtypes
x    string
y     Int64
dtype: object
>>> df.groupby(["x"], as_index=False).sum().dtypes
x    object
y     Int64
dtype: object
>>> df.groupby(["x"]).sum().reset_index().dtypes
x    object
y     Int64
dtype: object
```

Is this a bug or an expected behaviour?
I can of course convert dtypes again after the groupby, but that's very annoying.
And not keeping the string dtype is causing issues in merges later in the code due to inconsistent column dtypes...

Any help to resolve this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bug. `string` will be consider as `object` class in `pandas` while calculation. You can also check the `type` of each cell

```
df.applymap(type)
Out[72]: 
               x              y
0  <class 'str'>  <class 'int'>
1  <class 'str'>  <class 'int'>
df.groupby(["x"], as_index=False).sum().applymap(type)
Out[73]: 
               x              y
0  <class 'str'>  <class 'int'>
1  <class 'str'>  <class 'int'>
```

Ans you could also convert the column back to your original follow with `astype`

```
d = {"x":"string", "y":"Int64"})
df.groupby(["x"], as_index=False).sum().astype(d)
```